# Does Java RMI IIOP work over internet?

Tags: java, rmi

I know that RMI is short on making connection outside LAN. I want to know if RMI IIOP can connect server client over internet. Is it possible ? If yes what are the possible solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RMI works fine over the internet, it's TCP-based. I'd use [KryoNet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) as an RMI implementation, personally. It's no-hassle, and extremely speedy. The serialisation mechanism uses Kryo, which is one of the fastest general purpose serialisation libraries. Note that there may be issues with firewalls. However, you could easily have an RMI server that listens on port 80. This would be work fine (unless there is heavy packet snooping, I guess). [An RMI server that works over HTTP is interesting too.](http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csneal/InternetComputing/Tunnelling.html) Mmm.

Comment: Some JavaEE container implementation provides RMI over HTTP like WebSphere for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if the ports are open at the firewall.  The advantage to using HTTP instead of RMI is that it can easily be passed through proxy servers.

Answer (score 0):

There's no particular advantage to using IIOP over the native RMI protocol JRMP, as far as Internet-wide usage is concerned.

IIOP *does* gives you the ability to call your Java objects using non-Java based code, so if you want to support non-Java clients, you'll want to be thinking about IIOP or something more browser / JavaScript friendly like SOAP or XMLRPC.

If you don't need to support non-Java clients, there's not much to recommend IIOP.  With IIOP, you lose the distributed garbage collection that JRMP provides, so you'll have to decide when any RMI-published object should no longer be published.

With JRMP, all you have to worry about manually managing are the RMI objects you bind to the RMI registry.  All other objects you publish will be automatically garbage collected once all references to them (both local and remote) are dropped.  If you use IIOP, you'll manually have to call PortableRemoteObject.unexportObject() when it's time to take them out of use.